# Why won't my method return anything?

Tags: java

Here is my code, when I go to compile and run the code, it returns nothing which I don't understand because I have return statements in the If and the Else.

```
public class Program8
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        getMonth("02/12/96");
    }

    public static int getMonth(String date)
    {
        if(date.substring(0,1).equals("0")) 
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(date.substring(1,2));
        }
        else 
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but your check if the first digit is `0` is unnecessary. `Integer.parseInt` would also parse `"02"` as `2`.

Answer (score 4):

Your method `getMonth` does return a value, but it is just discarded in the `main` method.

Probably you wanted to print it, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(getMonth("02/12/96"));
}
```

Or log it, or out make it somehow visible to the user (e.g. GUI), or assign it to a variable like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int month = getMonth("02/12/96"); 
    // now `month` can be used for the subsequent operations/calculations
}
```

and then use the variable value in further calculations.

Answer (score 2):

You are not outputting anything. Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(getMonth("02/12/96"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the returned variable to the console.

e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(getMonth("02/12/96"));
}
```

The programm can't know if you want to print the month in the console.